# Deploy application and database in WPF

Tags: wpf, installation, clickonce

I have a WPF application and it has a SQL Server database. All users of the application will be able to do the following:

1. Be able to install the application locally, and also the database (blank tables with no data) using a single click. Henceforth they will be able to run the application locally on their own machines. All the users have SQL Server installed on their machines.
2. Be able to get updates (or notification of updates) on the application and database, and will be able to install the updates if they choose to do so.

I realize that ClickOnce can do it for the application only. Now since I have the database along with the application, how can I do it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your users have the adequate permissions over their database (which I hope they have) you could simply check that the DB is ready at application Startup, and if not, run the creation scripts on it.

Comment: The user who will be running the application will have nothing except a blank SQL Server box. The installation should create the database and also the user needed to log into the database. Can you please tell how I can do that?

Comment: Yes, but which user can access the blank SQL Server? Who has admin rights on it? Do you use Windows Authentication? If true, what are the permissions on the SQL Server for the current user?

Comment: When the user will install the application, the database will also be created as part of the installation. The user will have admin rights on his machine and on the SQL Server that he is running locally.

Comment: then in your installation run the SQL Scripts creating the DB and it's tables, SP etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an SQL Server compact database along with your application. Sample here: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-deploy-the-sqlserver-compact-edition-software-locally/ 
For SQL Server 2005 / 2008 the user must use the Microsoft provided installers.